# How to integrate DialogFlow V2 in Android?

Tags: android, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I've implemented DialogFlow with the help of [
Create a Conversational Interface for Android With Dialogflow]
  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-conversational-interface-for-android-with-dialogflow--cms-30845 and It was working like a charm. Now DialogFlow has migrated its API from V1 to V2, because of that I'm not getting any response from https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/  every time I hit this API I get a response "Not Found".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dialogflow Android SDK](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client). It works for me on V1 and V2. There are code snippets and documentation on how to use it and integrate it in Android. 
But this won't give you the chat UI. You will need to develop that on your own Android UI. You can reuse the Dialogflow agent with this SDK.

**Update**

If you are still looking to integrate Dialogflow into an Android project, take a look into my library. It will help you easily integrate a chatbot with complete UI in your app
https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-dialogflow-chatbot-library-6b7b3822e7bc

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the Dialogflow [Android libraries](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) and the other is to use the third-party applications which support DialogflowV2 and integrates with Android which also supports customizations and actionable messages. Please refer to this [article](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/build-chatbot-with-dialogflow-android-sdk/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

We created an [Android Dialogflow client lib (Dialogflow v2)](https://github.com/Educards/android-dialogflow) which uses the officially supported [Dialogflow Java lib](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/java).